# Qt/QML: Putting WebEngineView in a ListView and calling loadHtml()

Tags: c++, listview, qml, qtwebengine

If I have a `WebEngineView` in a `ListView` delegate, how can I call `loadHtml` when the delegate is loaded? For example:

```
ListView
{
    model: myModel

    delegate: Component
    {
        Item:
        {
            WebEngineView
            {
                id: myWebView
                text: myWebView.loadHtml(model.modelData.htmlText) 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above shows the idea of what I would like to do. Is there a signal I could hook into for each delegate Item where I could call `myWebView.loadHtml()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know about a `text`-property of the [`WebEngineView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebengine-webengineview.html) but I have never used it sofar.

I think, what you want is the `Component.onCompleted`-handler like this:

```
ListView {
    model: myModel
    delegate: Component {
        Item {
            WebEngineView {
                id: myWebView
                Component.onCompleted: loadHtml(model.modelData.htmlText, baseURL)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know about your usecase, but the [`loadHtml`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebengine-webengineview.html#loadHtml-method)-method has a second argument for the `baseURL` to look for ressources such as CSS or Images, which might be needed by you.